# 『詳細！Python 3 入門ノート』p.34-35について

Tags: python, python3

大重美幸『詳細！Python 3 入門ノート』p.34-35にあるコードをテキスト（atom）で保存して実行したのですがエラーが出ます。同書のサポートサイトのサンプルファイルを実行しようとしても同じエラーが出ます。どこを訂正すれば実行可能になるのでしょうか

コード

```py
kosu = 12 * 5
print(kosu)
```

エラー

```
>>> python C:\Users\■■■■\Desktop\Python3_sample\Python3_sample\Part1\Section2-3\calc.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python C:\Users\■■■■\Desktop\Python3_sample\Python3_sample\Part1\Section2-3\calc.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　今回は私が修正してしまいましたが、次回からこのサイトでは、コードやエラー出力はスクリーンショットではなく、テキストをそのままコピペして頂ければ幸いです。後から検索しやすいようにするためです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

コマンドラインと Python インタプリタを混同しています。

`python ファイル名` というコマンドは、コマンドプロンプトなどの上で打つコマンドです。対して現在は Python インタプリタ上でこれを実行なさっているようです（Python インタプリタとは、単に `python` と打って実行すると起動するもののことです）。 `exit()` と打って Python インタプリタを終了し、コマンドプロンプトの入力待ち状態に戻ってから `python ファイル名` を打ち込んでください。

Comment: nekketsuuu様　exit() と打って 、python ファイル名を打ち込んだところ実行できました。ありがとうございます

Comment: お疲れ様でした。もしよろしければ[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)して頂けると、僕が嬉しいです :-)